# Simple guessing game in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, number-guessing-game

Here is a simple Guessing Game I implemented in Haskell

```
import System.Random
import Text.Read 

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "I am guessing a value between 1 to 100"
  guess <- (randomIO :: IO Int)
  playWith (guess `mod` 100)
  putStrLn "Play again? (Y/N)"
  response <- getLine
  if response == "Y" then
    main
  else
    return ()

playWith :: Int -> IO ()
playWith n = go 5
  where
  go 0 = putStrLn "You loose!"
  go n = do
    putStr "Enter your guess: "
    guess <- readUntilValid 
    if n == guess then
      putStrLn "You win!"
    else
      if n < guess then
          putStrLn "Too large!" >> go (n-1)
      else
          putStrLn "Too small!" >> go (n-1)

readUntilValid :: IO Int
readUntilValid = do
  s <- getLine
  case (readMaybe s :: Maybe Int) of
    Nothing -> putStr "Please enter a valid guess:" >> readUntilValid
    Just x -> return x
```

Is there something I can (or should) do to prevent the usage of goto like recursion? Maybe I could use something from `Control.Monad`?

Answer (score 6):

Great job on writing `readUntilValid` as a separate function instead of inlining it in `playWith`. That being said, we can go a little bit further with splitting the functionality of your code.

At the moment, your `main` contains five distinct steps:

- greet the user with the rules
- choose a random number
- start the game
- ask whether the user wants to play again
- restart

The random number is part of the game, so it's a little bit strange to generate it in `main`. Your function `playWith` already suggests a name for a another function that takes care of that step:

```
play :: IO ()
play = randomRIO (1, 100) >>= playWith
```

`randomRIO` takes a range, so we end up with the correct numbers. Your program choosed numbers between 0-99, by the way.

However, now we can also get the rules in there:

```
import Control.Monad (when)
import System.Random (randomRIO)
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

play :: IO ()
play = do
  putStrLn "I am guessing a value between 1 to 100."
  randomRIO (1, 100) >>= playWith

main :: IO ()
main = do
  play
  response <- prompt "Play again? (Y/N)"
  when (response == "Y") main

prompt :: String -> IO String
prompt xs = putStr (xs ++ " ") >> getLine
```

The `prompt` is just a little helper for questions to the user. What did we gain from splitting `main`? Well, `main` does not have to care for the game at all. We can replace `play` by any other game, e.g. `playTicTacToe`, and we don't have to change our `main` at all. So try to isolate your code a little bit.

Next we have `playWith`. There's a bug in there, you use `n` twice, once as (correct) answer, once as the number of turns the user has. Therefore, they have to guess `5`, `4`, and so on. The original random number wasn't used at all. Let's fix that first:

```
playWith :: Int -> IO ()
playWith answer = go 5
  where
  go 0 = putStrLn "You loose!"
  go n = do
    putStr "Enter your guess: "
    guess <- readUntilValid 
    if answer == guess then
      putStrLn "You win!"
    else
      if answer < guess then
          putStrLn "Too large!" >> go (n-1)
      else
          putStrLn "Too small!" >> go (n-1)
```

Note that GHC will warn you about shadowing if you use `-Wall`. But we can still do better. If you're going to compare two values and want to act on more than a single outcome, use `compare` instead of two checks (here `==`  and `<`):

```
playWith :: Int -> IO ()
playWith answer = go 5
  where
  go 0 = putStrLn "You lost!"
  go n = do
    putStr "Enter your guess: "
    guess <- readUntilValid

    case guess `compare` answer of
      EQ -> putStrLn "You win!"
      LT -> putStrLn "Too small!" >> go (n-1)
      GT -> putStrLn "Too large!" >> go (n-1)
```

And now back to `readUntilValid` As I said, it's completely fine, however the additional type signature isn't necessary, as the compiler can infer `readMaybe`'s type in that context. We end up with:

```
readUntilValid :: IO Int
readUntilValid = do
  s <- getLine
  case readMaybe s of
    Nothing -> putStr "Please enter a valid guess:" >> readUntilValid
    Just x  -> return x
```

Note that you can even write it as

```
readUntilValid :: Read a => IO a
```

but that's an aside. We end up with

```
import Control.Monad (when)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  play
  response <- prompt "Play again? (Y/N)"
  when (response == "Y") main

play :: IO ()
play = do
  putStrLn "I am guessing a value between 1 to 100."
  randomRIO (1, 100) >>= playWith

playWith :: Int -> IO ()
playWith answer = go 5
  where
  go 0 = putStrLn "You lost!"
  go n = do
    guess <- askNumber

    case guess `compare` answer of
      EQ -> putStrLn "You win!"
      LT -> putStrLn "Too small!" >> go (n-1)
      GT -> putStrLn "Too large!" >> go (n-1)

prompt :: String -> IO String
prompt xs = putStr (xs ++ " ") >> getLine

askNumber :: IO Int
askNumber = do
  response <- prompt "Please enter your guess (1-100): "
  case readMaybe response of
    Nothing -> putStrLn "Not a valid guess, try again." >> askNumber
    Just x  -> return x
```

I've renamed `readUntilValid` and also let it ask the number, so that again everything that is concerned with getting input from the user resides in a single function.

All in all, well done. Don't be afraid to split your functions, make sure to enable compiler warnings, and use `hlint` (it suggested `when` from `Control.Monad`, by the way).

#### Exercises

- at the moment, the user will only replay the game if they enter `Y`. Also accept other inputs, such as "yes", "YES" and "y", and ask again if they don't say "yes" or "no" in a clear way
- the number of guesses is currently fixed in `playWith`. Make it variable
- the range is currently fixed (1-100). Make it variable
- have the user choose a difficulty. The difficulty should determine the original range as well as the number of guesses. Keep the lower difficulty levels fair, e.g.

  ```
   difficulty   | range      | guesses
  --------------+------------+-------------------------------
   trivial      | 1-10       | 10
   easy         | 1-100      | 10
   medium       | 1-100      | 7
   hard         | 1-1000     | 10 -- still fair
   harder       | 1-10000    | 13 -- beginning to get unfair
   hardest      | 1-1000000  | 17 -- missing three guesses
   lucky        | 1-20       | 1
  ```
- the user doesn't know how many guesses they have. You should probably tell them at some point, especially with difficulty levels
- instead of `()`, `playWith` could return `data GameEnd = Won | Lost`, but that's just for style and not necessary. You could use that information for statistics and so on, but that's an overkill

Have fun.

Answer (score 0):

`playWith` and `go` both call their argument `n`, leading to mixups.

`mod` maps the integers to `[0.99]`, not `[1..100]`.

You are looking for `Control.Monad.Loops`.

```
import Control.Monad.Loops (allM, orM, untilJust)

main = void $ allM (== "Y") $ repeat $ do
  putStrLn "I am guessing a value between 1 to 100"
  value <- randomRIO (1,100) :: IO Int
  win <- orM $ replicate 5 $ do
    putStr "Enter your guess: "
    guess <- untilJust $ do
      mguess <- readMaybe <$> getLine :: IO (Maybe Int)
      unless (isJust mguess) $ putStr "Please enter a valid guess: "
      return mguess
    when (guess < value) $ putStrLn "Too large!"
    when (guess > value) $ putStrLn "Too small!"
    return $ guess == value
  putStrLn $ "You " ++ if win then "win!" else "lose!"
  putStrLn "Play again? (Y/N)"
  getLine
```

Comment: While the code you present does have the same behaviour, it's an entirely different ballpark of complex. I don't like how you've inlined both extracted functions, while rewriting them significantly without any comment. I think it would help OP a lot if you could be significantly more explicit in your rewriting process

Comment: If extracting the inner do blocks would help, the reader can simply ignore all code that starts successively further from the left for the same effect.